# i need to know how to put some unix commands like echo and awk in python script

Tags: python

I need to embed unix commands in python script and need a piece of code to perform the below:
   echo $i |awk -F ' ' '{print $9' '$6' '$7' '$8}'

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238180/execute-shell-commands-in-python

Answer (score 0):

in python you can run shell commands like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```